# Python hex conversions on function return

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, micropython

I have a board that returns a byte type with the value in it: `b'\x0126.381\x00\x00\x00'`

When I have this returned in a function it automatically formats the return as a float:

```py
def read(address, command, seconds, length):
  i2c.writeto(address, command)
  time.sleep(seconds)
  result = i2c.readfrom(address, length).decode("utf-8")
  return result
# Returns 26.381
```

If I print this result it gives me the correct `26.381` and if I do

```py
print(type(read(a, c, s, l)))
# Returns <class: 'str'>
```

However if I try to add this value to a dictionary:

```py
results = dict()
results["test"] = read(a, c, s, l)
print(results)
# Returns {'test': '\x0126.381\x00\x00\x00'}
```

Im using micropython on the Raspberry Pi Pico however I'm assuming this is also an issue in Python3 as well.

Comment: Its it better if you have: `return result.strip('/x00')[1:]`?

Comment: @quamrana That would work however does not deal with the trailing "\x00\x00". I know you could brute force it using string manipulation however after some research it seems to have something to do with the str() and repr() functions. Still trying to find an answer though as this doesnt fix it in a dictionary

Comment: But your trailing characters are `"/x00"`.

Comment: @quamrana Ah sorry my mistake, because this is a stream of data you cant always assume that it will trail with "\x00" however Python seems to intuitively do this when returned from a function. This answer also wont split the \x01 at the beginning.

Comment: @quamrana Technically you could use ```result.split('\x01')[1].replace('\x00', '')``` however this still doesnt solve the mystery

Comment: You had better update your question with the correct information. Is it ‘/x00’ or ‘\x00’? Also what is the device you are communicating with?

Comment: @quamrana sorry it is "\x00". The device that is reading it is a Raspberry Pi Pico however I can't see why this is important to the question. This is a micropython question surely?

Comment: Ok, I'll run my code again to see what is happening. But about the `i2c.readfrom`. What is the device on the other end of the `i2c` bus?

Comment: So, just stripping the nulls and the first char works: `return result.strip('\x00')[1:]`

Comment: @quamrana Again I agree that your answer would work I was just curious as to why this behaviour exists in Python

Comment: @quamrana Unfortunately I cant say what the device is due to an NDA agreement

Comment: What behaviour? I contend that the device at the other end of the `i2c` bus seems to be returning a sequence of bytes. Now `python` has to deal with the results the best it can. It may be better to refer to the documentation of the device. It may describe how the data is encoded.

Comment: The behaviour in which when hex is returned in a function it returns with just the value but if that returned value is used in a dict it gives the hex value

Comment: That's not a thing. Probably down to representations. Lists and dicts call `__repr__()` on their contents.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you @quamrana, do you want to put that as the answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to start with a fixed byte string carefully chosen to produce consistent results and show how the decoded version prints differently whether its used as a string or is held in a container.

```py
def read():   # parameters elided
    readfrom = b'\x0126.381'
    print(readfrom, '         <========== byte array')
    result = readfrom.decode("utf-8")
    return result

data = read()  # as if reading from an `i2c` device

results = dict()
results["test"] = data

print(data, '                <========== string')
print(results, ' <========== dict')
print(results["test"], '                <========== string again')
print(repr(results["test"]), '            <========== repr of string')
```

Output:

```
b'\x0126.381'          <========== byte array
26.381                 <========== string
{'test': '\x0126.381'}  <========== dict
26.381                 <========== string again
'\x0126.381'             <========== repr of string
```

Comment: Thats great but how do you go back from repr to the string?

Comment: In my code, `data` is a string already because the `read()` function returns a string which is the return type from the `decode()` method. You have asked both of us questions, but we are both struggling to understand what you mean. We are so ingrained in `python` that we can't decode the python-like terms that you are using into what you actually mean.

Comment: if I use @ukBaz 's answer for the variables this is what I mean, in the function you return str_value from the raw_value, when this gets added as the value of a dictionary entry it returns key: repr_value what I'm asking is how can you get just key: str_value

Comment: You seem to be under the misapprehension that how a value is printed (ie represented) is what the value actually is. This is not the case. When the string is returned, then its value is fixed (btw strings are immutable). You can store that string in a variable and/or in your `results` `dict` and the value does not change. I have to agree with @ukBaz and say that I'm sure you are after the `float` version - although you should say what you want to do with this value after it is stored in the `dict`.

Comment: Um yes I will need it as a float as after I get this value I send it to a database via json and the schema says it has to be a float

Comment: So, should you just go straight for the `float` version?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the documentation of the device it is difficult to be definitive on how to handle the returned value. However, in your question you suggest that the expected return value should be a float. I would suspect that the leading `b'\x01'` has some special meaning (e.g. what type of value has been returned). The `b'\x00'`'s at the end are null bytes and also not printable.

For this answer I shall identify the `b'\x01'` and `b'\x00'` as non-printable characters and ignore them.

The characters that are left should be a string representations of a floating point number.

It would seem sensible to convert the "string float" to an actual Python float before storing it in the dictionary.

For example:

```py
>>> raw_value = b'\x0126.381\x00\x00\x00'
>>> print(type(raw_value), raw_value)
<class 'bytes'> b'\x0126.381\x00\x00\x00'
>>> str_value = raw_value.decode('utf8')
>>> print(type(str_value), str_value)
<class 'str'> □26.381
>>> printable_value = ''.join(c for c in str_value if c.isprintable())
>>> print(type(printable_value), printable_value)
<class 'str'> 26.381
>>> float_value = float(printable_value)
>>> print(type(float_value), float_value)
<class 'float'> 26.381
>>> results = dict()
>>> results["test"] = float_value
>>> print(results)
{'test': 26.381}
```

In summary, there are three stages by which the original returned bytes are transformed:

1. decode bytes to string as 'utf8'
2. Use `isprintable()` function to find printable characters
3. Convert string representation of float value to a Python float

Comment: When I tried running some code to decode the bytes, the string contained everything that the bytes array contained, including the nulls.

Comment: Did you filter using `isprintable`?

Comment: Well, no. I didn’t think of that. I thought your conversion was the decode from utf8.

Comment: There are three parts: 1) decode('utf8') 2) isprintable() and 3) float()

Comment: This is great however it automatically does this when you return the raw_value from a function. The question is why does python do this instead of returning the raw_value in its native byte type?

Comment: When you print just the return value it shows the  `__str__` of the Python `str` class . When you print the dict it shows the `__repr__` value of the `str` class. This is why you are seeing different representations of the return value in different circumstances. I think the best approach is if your `read` function returns a `float` and not a `str` class

Comment: The `__repr__` goal is to be unambiguous while the 
`__str__` goal is to be readable